# Download Multiple Email Attachments & Rename them

Tags: vba, outlook

I receive emails from >10 different stores every day. Each email usually has more than one attachment. I download each email's attachments into the respective local sub-directories.

I download the attachments using a code I found online. I coupled the script with rules so attachments download to their respective local folders.

Problem: Let's say that store 1 sends a file with name ABC.xlsx every day. My rules/ script run, in a reverse chronological order and thus the script goes through each mail one by one and each file replaces the latest file until I get the earliest file.

I need my script to either save the latest file, or more appropriately, update the file name with current date appended to the existing file name.

```vb
Public Sub SaveAttachmentsToDisk_St10(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim sSaveFolder As String
    sSaveFolder = "H:\Folder1\Projects\Online\Data\Store 10\MC\"
    For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
        oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.DisplayName
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the date from your mail item using [ReceivedTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.receivedtime). This returns a date, use this with the `Format` function to create a suffix that you append to the filename. I would suggest to put the date as YYYYMMDD, that helps sorting the filenames.

```
For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
    Dim filename As String, p As Long, suffix As String
    filename = oAttachment.DisplayName
    suffix = "_" & Format(MItem.ReceivedTime, "YYYYMMDD_HHNN")
    ' Now add the suffix before the file extension
    p = InStrRev(filename, ".")    ' Find dot to separate file extension
    If p > 0 Then
        filename = Left(filename, p - 1) & suffix & Mid(filename, p)
    Else
        filename = filename & suffix
    End If
    oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & filename
Next
```

Comment: Hi Thomas,
Thankyou for your response, however, the script results in the same response, the files are getting stored by their present names and not with received time.
(Please note that I am completely new to VBA, so what I did was just replace your code with the 5th, 6th and 7th rows of the original code)

Comment: Sorry, did a small mistake, obviously you need to use the created filename in the `SaveAsFile`. Updated my answer